# Why is auto import for JS/TS `export { foo as default }` not working in VS Code 1.80 or below?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

```js
// foo.ts
const foo = 'foo';
export default foo;
```

```js
// bar.ts
const bar = 'bar'
export { bar as default };
```

The `foo` module is able to be auto-imported, but the `bar` module is not in the options.

Is this intended or a miss?

Expect both `foo` and `bar` module to be auto-imported when typing `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: lol I found you in two other places while trying to google for existing issue tickets :P https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54839 and https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/14mbj5n/auto_import_for_export_as_default/

Answer (score 0):

The fix for the issue has been made in this Pull Request: [Fix export as default not auto importing #54871](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/54871). The fix will probably be available in the next TypeScript release (5.2?)

Nicely, this was raised as an issue ticket by the asker of this question, which I found by googling `site:github.com issues javascript OR typescript auto import export "as default"`: [Auto Import for export as default is not working #54839](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54839) (I was searching for existing ones before possibly raising one of my own).